# How to change the default color of BottomSheet to transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried numerous ways to change the default white background to transparent

1. List item
2. Changing my root layout color to transparent
3. Changing the window color of bottomsheet to transparent programmatically by implementing following code.

   ```
   bottomsheetdialog.getwindow()
                    .setBackgroungDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
   ```

None of the above worked.
Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: make sure all your bottomsheet content views background is set to transparent !! *`Not only the root Layout`*

Comment: Could you please provide me with some sort of example?

Comment: post your bottom sheet layout first !!

Comment: Picture or code?

Comment: code is better !!